SharePoint List - Extract Year & Quarter from Date Field
Wondering how I can have the read-only (calculated columns for Year & Quarter) and show nothing if the date field is blank.
Currently I have the formulas for these two columns as:
Display Year:
=TEXT([RFQ Issue Date],"yyyy")

Display Quarter:
="Q"&CHOOSE(MONTH([RFQ Issue Date]),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4)


Use formula like below for your SharePoint calculated columns:
Display Year:
=IF(ISBLANK([RFQ Issue Date]),"",TEXT([RFQ Issue Date],"yyyy"))

Display Quarter:
=IF(ISBLANK([RFQ Issue Date]),"","Q"&CHOOSE(MONTH([RFQ Issue Date]),1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4))

Output:

Note:

Sometimes comma(,) does not work in formula (it is based on language or regional settings on your site). So in that case use semicolon(;) instead of comma(,).
Use correct display name of your SharePoint columns in above formula.
Wrap column names inside [] if your column name has space in it. For example: [My Column Name].

